# How do I know if a Legendary item can be obtained at Kadala?

Tags: diablo-iii

Reaper of Soul has introduced with [Kadala](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Kadala) a system of gambling. I know that you can get legendaries from her but I don't know if every legendary in the game can be obtained by gambling.

How do I know if a legendary can be gained through gambling or not ?

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau Marking a old question as duplicate of a new one because the new one is more "general" is a bad practice (or as stated by LessPop ["monstruous"](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7901/what-do-you-do-when-a-question-is-asked-which-is-a-collection-of-other-asked-que#comment23087_7901)) and not encouraged. Plus as stated on [this relevant Meta Question](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7359/is-a-question-a-duplicate-just-because-it-asks-for-something-that-can-be-part-of) globally duplicate answer does not mean duplicate question.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau My goal here was to make a question that prevent future asker to feel the need to ask their question for every legendary and have a more general answer to cover this topic.

Comment: Those meta posts aren't actually covering this case, as the answers of the old questions are exactly the same as this one or just less specific on what Kadala drops. There's only 2 other questions on this, the older being from April.

Comment: Futhermore, you answered one of the other questions with a very similar answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We can distinguish 5 kinds of legendaries :

- "Regular" legendaries : can drop anywhere in the game, at any difficulty
- [Legendary crafting Plan](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/blacksmith-plan/#type=legendary) : can drop anywhere in the game
- [Torment-only legendaries](http://www.diablowiki.net/Torment-only) : can only drop in Torment 1 difficulty and above
- [Legendaries Potion](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/potion/) : can drop in Torment 1 difficulty and above
- [Horadric Cache-only legendaries](http://www.diablowiki.net/Horadric_Cache#Horadric_Cache-only_Items) : can be found only in a Horadric Cache

Among those 5 types :

Kadala can give you only Regular ones and Torment-only ones ([since patch 2.0.5](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/14138344/patch-205-now-live-5-13-2014#amkadala)). Since you can gamble in every difficulty, you can hypothetically obtain a Torment-Only legendary in Normal difficulty by gambling (though it requires some luck).

Kadala can neither give Plans  nor Potion (since she does not sell any of those). She can't neither give Cache-only legendaries  :those are still reserved as a reward for completing bounties.

Short answer : If you want to know if you can obtain a legendary at Kadala, just look in which category it belongs. If it's not a Plan/Potion or a Cache-only legendary, you can get it at Kadala.

Comment: To further extend the correct answer, this also works for set legendaries. since 2.0.5 you can get every legendary and set ITEM of Kadala, including class specific sets.

Comment: @De5tr0yer yes, those are mentionned, they are the "Torment-only" legendaries

Comment: sorry, but if you want to be nitpicky with all those legendary divisions you have to additionally summon the set items. Set items are not torment-only legendaries. For instance, the all-so-known Blackthorn set is not torment only.

Comment: @De5tr0yer set items are not all torment only but torment-only gear are all set item (given on the link). The other set items are counted in the "Regular legendareis" which include as you just mentionned the BlzackThorne set.

Comment: And that is why I have written "to further extend the correct answer" in the first place. There is always someone who asks "what about set items", so here he can find the answer automatically.